# Bash: variable does not get populated

Tags: bash, variables

Originally from: [IF grep finds what it is looking fore do X else Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024828/if-grep-finds-what-it-is-looking-fore-do-x-else-y) but the original question was answered.

$@ has the value of "Load firefox/3.6.12"

```
var1=$(echo "$@" | grep -Eio '\s\w*') # Gets the application name and put it into var1
echo $var1   # is not printed should be "firefox"
var2=$(echo "$@" | grep -o '[^/]*$')  # Gets version name and put it into var2 
echo $var2 # prints fine
```

The regex is fine, it has worked before one time before i changed some thing

Edit:
There is something wrong with

```
var1=$(echo "$@" | grep -Eio '\s\w*') #expected result is: firefox
```

I works fine if i use

```
var1="firefox"
```

I must have changed something a some point.

Edit:
SOLUTION

```
echo "Load firefox/6.12.3" | awk ‘{print $2}’ | cut -f1 -d”/”
```

Grep is no longer used.

Comment: Check your input ($@). I just loaded your script and ran it as ./script Load firefox/3.6.12 and I got the expected output you are looking for.

Comment: must have a brain freeze. This does not work:

echo "Load firefox/6.12.3" | grep -Eio '\s\w*'

Comment: Might be your system. That prints "firefox" to stdout on mine.

Comment: so strange sins:  
# echo "Load firefox/6.12.3" | grep -Eio '[^/]*$'   Gives: 
6.12.3. I have tried several different systems RHEL and SLES

Comment: Solution, skipped grep ans used awk/cut: echo "Load firefox/6.12.3" | awk ‘{print $2}’ | cut -f1 -d”/”

Answer (score 0):

try echoing out the find before running it - it does seem you need to trim the text for var1 var2

**echo "find /app/$var1 -noleaf -maxdepth 1 -type l -o -type d | grep $var2"**

```
if find /app/$var1 -noleaf -maxdepth 1 -type l -o -type d | grep $var2; then
```

find /app/ **firefox** -noleaf -maxdepth 1 -type l -o -type d | grep 3.6.12

so try :

```
var1=${var1//[[:space:]]}
var2=${var2//[[:space:]]}
if find /app/$var1 -noleaf -maxdepth 1 -type l -o -type d | grep $var2; then
```

Comment: The error is in this line

var1=$(echo "$@" | grep -Eio '\s\w*') 

I manually filled the variable with "firefox" and it worked. The regex worked in an external regexprogram called Expresso.

Comment: :) I know which is why I outputted the echo output with firefox in bold above anyhow rather than all the space addition change var1 to var1=$(echo "$abc" | grep -Eio '\s\w*'|sed -e 's/ //g')